# Array of Path using nio

Tags: java, nio

I'm just studying topic nio  and got the following  task:
do recursive search of file name using nio. The method should return a list of found Path.
When I run the code below in output I see only **[ ]**. Could someone explain and correct me?

```
public class Task01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path dir = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\......");
        System.out.println(findFile(dir, "Task01.java"));
    }

    public static ArrayList<Path> findFile(Path path, String filename) throws IOException {
        Path dir = Paths.get("C:\\....");
        ArrayList<Path> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path, filename)) {
            for (Path entry : stream) {
                if (path.toFile().isDirectory()) {
                    findFile(path, filename);
                } else list1.add(entry.toAbsolutePath());
            }

        }
        return list1;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your ```if..else``` statements, use ```entry``` instead of ```path```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may work for you:

```
public static ArrayList<Path> findFile(Path path, String filename) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Path> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path,filename)) {
        for (Path entry : stream) {
            System.out.println(entry+ "-"+entry.getFileName());
            if (Files.isDirectory(entry)) {
                list1.addAll(findFile(entry, filename));
            } 
            else if (entry.getFileName().toString().equals(filename)) 
                list1.add(entry.toAbsolutePath());
        }

    }
    return list1;
}
```

- When passing filename to Files.newDirectoryStream(path,filename) it will only search in the path itself, no subdirectories. So you may not pass the filename here to filter.
- if you call your method recursively you must also make sure the return values are passed upwards: `list1.addAll(findFile(entry, filename));`
- within the for loop always work with `entry`, not `path` otherwise you are not processing your directory structure recursively. (see `Files.isDirectory(entry)` instead of `path.toFile().isDirectory()`

UPDATE: improved usage of java.nio API (thanks to @Andreas). It's correct I'm less familiar with the `nio` api.

Comment: Up-voted, but: Don't mix old and new APIs, unless absolutely necessary, so don't call `toFile()`! --- Don't use `entry.toFile().isDirectory()`, use `Files.isDirectory(entry)`. --- Don't use `entry.toFile().getName()`, use `entry.getFileName().toString()`. Better yet, use `else if (entry.endsWith(filename)) `. --- Also, `entry.getName(entry.getNameCount()-1)` is a very long-winded way of writing `entry.getFileName()`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when doing the recursion, you want to use `entry` instead of `path`, otherwise you are not going down the directory tree.

Also use `Files.newDirectoryStream(path)` instead of `Files.newDirectoryStream(path, fileNamePattern)` the second method creates a stream in the path whose filename matches fileNamePattern, in your case it will be empty `[]` if your `Test.java` is not located in `path`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path dir = Paths.get("E:\\dev\\...");
    System.out.println(findFile(dir, "TestA.java"));
}

public static ArrayList<Path> findFile(Path path, String filename) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Path> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
        for (Path entry : stream) {
            if (Files.isDirectory(entry)) {
               list1.addAll(findFile(entry, filename));
            } else if(entry.getFileName().endsWith(filename)){
               list1.add(entry.toAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
    return list1;
}
```

Comment: Use `Files.isDirectory(entry)`. --- Why call `getName()` before `endsWith()`? It's unnecessary. Besides, `getFileName()` is a lot shorter/on-point than `getName(entry.getNameCount()-1)`, if you have to do that operation.

Comment: @Andreas correct, I made modification to the code based on your comments

Comment: No you didn't, you messed up the code when trying to apply the second part, and you didn't do the first part.